# How to configure SSL in Spring LDAP?

Tags: spring, ssl, active-directory

I am new to spring ldap and facing issue while connecting to LDAP over SSL.
I am using Spring LDAP 2.0 to connect LDAP.

```
applicationContext.xml

   <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:ldap.properties" ignore-  unresolvable="true"/>

   <ldap:context-source id="contextSource" password="${ldap.password}"
        url="${ldap.url}" username="${ldap.userDn}" base="${ldap.base}" >
   </ldap:context-source>

   <ldap:ldap-template id="ldapTemplate" context-source-ref="contextSource" />


Entries from Ldap property file:

   ldap.url=ldaps://eun4p3.stp-dev.st.com:636
   ldap.userDn=CN=IP User,OU=AdminAccounts,DC=stp-dev,DC=st,DC=com
   ldap.password=useme@123
   ldap.base=OU=ST,OU=People,DC=stp-dev,DC=st,DC=com
   ldap.clean=false
```

I have imported self signed certificate provided into cacerts file using :

```
   keytool -keystore cacerts -importcert -alias addevcer -file  C:\Users\kadianr\Desktop\eun4p3.cer
```

Below is the error I am getting while making call to ldaps://url:636

```
Caused by: org.springframework.ldap.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: eun4p3.stp-dev.st.com:636; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: eun4p3.stp-dev.st.com:636 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target]
    at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:108) [spring-ldap-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.createContext(AbstractContextSource.java:356) [spring-ldap-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.doGetContext(AbstractContextSource.java:140) [spring-ldap-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getReadWriteContext(AbstractContextSource.java:175) [spring-ldap-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.transaction.compensating.manager.TransactionAwareContextSourceProxy.getReadWriteContext(TransactionAwareContextSourceProxy.java:88) [spring-ldap-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.transaction.compensating.manager.TransactionAwareContextSourceProxy.getReadOnlyContext(TransactionAwareContextSourceProxy.java:61) [spring-ldap-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:357) [spring-ldap-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:309) [spring-ldap-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:642) [spring-ldap-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:578) [spring-ldap-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.find(LdapTemplate.java:1836) [spring-ldap-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.find(LdapTemplate.java:1857) [spring-ldap-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.findOne(LdapTemplate.java:1865) [spring-ldap-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at com.st.liotroevo.web.dao.UserADRepository.findBySamAccountName(UserADRepository.java:48) [classes:]
    at com.st.liotroevo.web.service.UserService.findUserBySamAccName(UserService.java:75) [classes:]
    at com.st.liotroevo.web.service.UserService.generateSamAccount(UserService.java:145) [classes:]
    at com.st.liotroevo.web.service.UserService.populateUserBaiscADAttributes(UserService.java:101) [classes:]
    at com.st.liotroevo.web.service.serviceImpl.IPRegistrationServiceImpl.createUser(IPRegistrationServiceImpl.java:48) [classes:]
    ... 39 more
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: eun4p3.stp-dev.st.com:636 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:215) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2740) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:316) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:193) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:211) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:154) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:84) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:153) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource.getDirContextInstance(LdapContextSource.java:42) [spring-ldap-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.createContext(AbstractContextSource.java:344) [spring-ldap-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    ... 55 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1886) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:882) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.run(Connection.java:849) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    ... 1 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1323) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_21]
    ... 12 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
```

I have been through documentation at http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-ldap/2.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/#configuration

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have resolved problem. Issue is with certificate installed in jdk. We tried installing different certificate signed by CA and that works. 
We just need to use ldaps with port 636 and install certificate in cacerts..thats it.

Comment: So problem was with use of self signed cert?  We having same problem , we have certificates in trust store too, we are having problem in cloud foundry, it works fine on local with same certs.

Comment: I used self signed cert and it worked fine.  I imported into  cacerts file thats under C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\security\cacerts

keytool  -importcert -alias mydevcert -trustcacerts -storepass changeit  -keystore cacerts -file LDAP_DEV.cer -noprompt

Answer (score 0):

If your company has an intranet site with its certificates you can actually just create a truststore at your application startup like this:

```
    final String KS_PASSWORD = "dummy";
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    ks.load(null, KS_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

    try (InputStream cert = new URL("http://pki.yourcompany.intranet/root.pem").openStream()) {
        Certificate certificate = cf.generateCertificate(cert);
        ks.setCertificateEntry(certificateName, certificate);
    }
    File keystore = new File("truststore.jks").getAbsoluteFile();
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(keystore)) {
        ks.store(fos, KS_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
    }
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", keystore.getAbsolutePath());
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", KS_PASSWORD);
```

Remember to set javax.* properties before Spring instantiates LDAP beans. Instead of going through the network you can also store certificates on the classpath (in your jar) and inject them using Spring's Resource.